# PHP Outputting multiple uploaded image by the user

Tags: php, html, image, upload

hello im looking to create a basic phot gallery website everything works got it to output users and images like instagram homepage but now im trying to ouput each users once and with 4 of their uploaded images, if users has more than 4 images uploaded only ouput 4, if less than 4 then output all.

its only outputting the name..but i want to output each users and 4 of their uploaded images.. any suggestion?

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM litrato_db JOIN users ON litrato_db.author_id = users.user_id GROUP BY user_id ") or die (mysqli_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $userName = $row['user_name'];
    echo $userName;

    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM litrato_db JOIN users ON litrato_db.image_id = users.user_id GROUP BY user_id") or die (mysqli_error());
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $imageTitle = $row['title'];
        $fileName = $row['filename'];
        $imageDesc = $row['caption'];
        $imageTimeDate = $row['timedate'];
        $imageId = $row['image_id'];
        // $userName = $row['user_name'];
        echo "<div class=\"posting\">";
        echo "<div class=\"thePoster\">"; 

        echo "<div class=\"thePostDate\">";
        echo "$imageTimeDate";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"thePost\">";
        echo "<p>$imageTitle</p>";
        echo "<a href =\"admin/detail.php?id=$imageId\">";          
        echo "<img src=\"thumbs/$fileName\"/>";
        echo "</a>";

        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";

    }
}
```